# Composer update does not run

Tags: linux, laravel, proxy, composer-php

When i run composer update it fails showing error:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                           
The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be     downloaded: failed to open stream:
```

Connection refused

If i visit the URL from my browser it goes through, when i try to **wget** or **curl** the URL from my terminal it shows error:

```
--2017-02-05 20:41:58--  https://packagist.org/packages.json
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8888... failed: 
Connection refused.

--2017-02-05 20:41:58--  https://packagist.org/packages.json
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8888... failed: Connection refused.
```

I think its something with proxy connection, but then i can't seem to solve the issue.

Bellow is the full trace if i run **composer update -vv**:

```
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Checked CA file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt: valid
Executing command (/var/www/gidiscrap): git branch --no-color --no-                     abbrev -v
Cannot create cache directory      /home/oluwaslim/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/oluwaslim/.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: /home/oluwaslim/.composer/composer.json
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
Reading /var/www/gidiscrap/vendor/composer/installed.json
Running 1.3.2 (2017-01-27 18:23:41) with PHP 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 on Linux / 4.4.0-59-generic
Loading composer repositories with package information
   Downloading https://packagist.org/packages.json using proxy 127.0.0.1:8888
   Downloading https://packagist.org/packages.json using proxy 127.0.0.1:8888
   Downloading https://packagist.org/packages.json using proxy 127.0.0.1:8888


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                           
  The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection refused  


Exception trace:
 () at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php:489
 Composer\Util\RemoteFilesystem->get() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php:101
 Composer\Util\RemoteFilesystem->getContents() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php:665
 Composer\Repository\ComposerRepository->fetchFile() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php:479
 Composer\Repository\ComposerRepository->loadRootServerFile() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php:258
 Composer\Repository\ComposerRepository->hasProviders() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php:99
 Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool->addRepository() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php:376
 Composer\Installer->doInstall() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php:223
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/UpdateCommand.php:158
 Composer\Command\UpdateCommand->execute() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:257
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:850
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:193
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:227
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:124
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:100
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/bin/composer:54
 require() at /usr/local/bin/composer:24
```

Help would be appriciated! I can't seem to get past this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am on Ubuntu Linux 16.04, and below is what i had to do to fix the issue, as i mentiond earlier its some problem with proxy settings.

Step 1

- Goto System settings
- Network
- Network proxy
- Change it to none
- finally click Apply system wide

Step 2

- Open terminal and type the following command.
  `unset https_proxy && unset socks_proxy && unset ftp_proxy`

Finally restart your system. The solution above got the issue solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

The line `using proxy 127.0.0.1:8888` suggest a problem with your system. I can guess that's a really aggressive antivirus. You should have no reason to connect to localhost on port 8888 unless you **have to** connect through proxy. What can you do? Check the antivirus settings and turn off checks for secure connections over HTTPS.

Comment: I don't have any anti virus intalled. i have Linux 16.04 installed

Comment: Do you use some kind of proxy? Tor maybe?

Comment: No! i don't remember installing any

Comment: Please check if `~/.wgetrc` exists in your home directory and check for proxy settings in it.

Comment: There is no such file or directory!! I know its a issue from my system